# How to make a centered Chapter in microsoft word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I've been wondering how can I make a chapter with the style like this. All that I can do is using multilevel list, then I define a new numbering, but it's still not centered.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use list? Why isn't out good what you've currently?  What should be different. Please clarify your question so wet can help better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to get involved in using style sets/theme sets, you can simply apply the "centered" paragraph attribute.

[image]

A better solution would be to modify an existing Heading style to include this attribute, and use the heading style instead; that will permit you to apply changes to font (face [including italics or small-caps], size, and weight), alignment (left/center/right), decoration (underlined/strikethrough), color, effects, and so on. This can get complex; I would recommend browsing Word’s help information if you wish to pursue this method.